# UserManager createuser method in Django raising NoneType not callable exception

Tags: python, django

made a view to automatically create new users but when I call that view I get this error " 'NoneType' object is not callable "

Heres the full stack trace:

```
    Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/krishna/Documents/temp/tutorial/quickstart/views.py" in RegistrationView
  24.         reg_user = UserManager.create_user(UserManager(), username=str(User.objects.all().count()+1), password=str(uuid.uuid4()))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in create_user
  187.                                  **extra_fields)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in _create_user
  180.                           date_joined=now, **extra_fields)

Exception Type: TypeError at /lkd/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Here is the view that is causing the problem:

```
def RegistrationView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        reg_user = UserManager.create_user(UserManager(), username=str(User.objects.all().count()+1), password=str(uuid.uuid4()))
        serialized_user = UserSerializer(reg_user)
        return JsonResponse(JSONRender.render(serialized_user.data))
    return HttpResponse("woah")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going about creating users in a difficult way. I suggest you look at the [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#creating-users) from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/).

Typically you don't access the manager directly. You probably want to do something similar to:

```
reg_user = User.objects.create_user(str(User.objects.all().count()+1), 'user@example.com', str(uuid.uuid4()))
reg_user.save()
```

instead of calling the UserManager.create_user method.